# Basic JavaScript crashes/hangs IE9, but not FF, Ch, or Op - "Not Implemented"

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, notimplementedexception

I get the following error:

> SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

On the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById("amtcase").style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";
```

"amtcase" is a text field

This only occurs on IE9, tested fine with Opera, Chrome, and FireFox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IE you can't assign the "style" attribute of a DOM node like that. You can do a couple of alternatives:

```
document.getElementById('amtcase').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('amtcase').style.cssText = 'background-color: #FFFFFF';
```

Comment: I didn't know **any** browser supported that method, let alone IE! +1!

Answer (score 4):

Do:

```
document.getElementById("amtcase").style["backgroundColor"] = "#FFFFFF";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("amtcase").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```